# Why is weight painting appearing on areas of my mesh I haven't painted?

Tags: weight-painting

I am having trouble with weight painting. I am not sure how to explain the issue very well.

Essentially, I need only the frame lock of a revolver to be painted -- but no matter what I do, only on this side of the model -- a little streak is getting painted too.

[image]

Could someone look at the .blend file and advise me on how to do this?
https://a.pomf.cat/jqyxqf.blend This is the .blend file.

Thanks.

Comment: just from looking at your picture it looks like the vertiex is connected to both parts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the fact the frame lock is not a separated part of the mesh. The vertices involved in your issue link the frame lock to the other part of your mesh. So this is a model problem not a weight paint problem.

You need to rip these vertices.

Doing that is a bit messy with this model as many tris are involved. But here is the principles :

- Go to edit mode
- In the modifier panel click on 'Display modifier in edit mode' and on 'adjust edit cage to modifier result' (in order to identify the good vertices easier)

[image]

So you can see that in edit mode when you move the frame lock bone :
[image]

Now the principle is to select the edge which links the two parts and rip it with <kbd>V</kbd>.
Then remove the unwanted vertices from the 'frame lock' group.

I had to repeat these two steps several times as the vertices are very intricated here. And that makes the detailed explanations hard to give here.

But the result :
[image]
[and the blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42391)

Comment: Do you have a Retina (high DPI) display? Just so you know, your screenshots are all double size—even on a Retina display! (I tend to either downsize them or move Blender to a second, regular-DPI display before taking a screenshot. Also, no offense meant, just trying to be helpful.)